# addEventListenerにより発生したcontextmenuが一度目の右クリックで表示されない

Tags: javascript, html, css

## 実現したいこと

下記ソースコードは、それぞれJavascript,css,HTMLとなっています。
このHTML内のid属性のcontextmenu1とcontextmenu2を右クリック表示させたいです。

contextmenu1は class="japan" 上で右クリックした際に、contextmenu2 はそれ以外の場所(id="menu"内)で右クリックした際に表示させたいのですが、下記ソースコードではclass="japan"リンク上で右クリックすると、contextmenu1が一度目は表示されず、二度目の右クリックから表示されてしまいます。
一度目の右クリックからcontextmenu1を表示させたいのですが、どのようなソースコードを書けばよいかご教授お願いいたします。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charser="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-width">
    <title>ここに記入した文字が上のタグに入る</title>

</head>
<style>
    #contextmenu1 {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 180px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #contextmenu li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #contextmenu2 {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 180px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #contextmenu2 li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<body onContextmenu="return false;">
    <div id="menu" style="width:100px; background-color:bisque; height: 300px;">
        <a class="japan" href="#">
            <p class="food">焼肉</p>
        </a>
        <a class="japan" href="#">
            <p class="food">寿司</p>
        </a>
        <a class="japan" href="#">
            <p class="food">ラーメン</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul id="contextmenu1">
        <li id="tokyo">東京</li>
        <li id="osaka">大阪</li>
        <li id="nagoya">名古屋</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="contextmenu2">
        <li>アメリカ</li>
        <li>イギリス</li>
        <li>フランス</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        let japan = document.getElementsByClassName('japan');
        let food = document.getElementsByClassName('food');
        let conme1 = document.getElementById('contextmenu1');
        let conme2 = document.getElementById('contextmenu2');

        window.onload = function () {

                menu.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
                
                            conme1.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
                            conme1.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
                            conme1.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示
                            conme2.style.display = "none";
                            
                    if (e.srcElement.className === "food") {//class=foodの場合
  　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　      　　　　　 for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
                             
                            food[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {//右クリックイベントを追加
                          
                            document.getElementById("tokyo").onclick = function () {
                                alert("東京の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                            document.getElementById("osaka").onclick = function () {
                                alert("大阪の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                            document.getElementById("nagoya").onclick = function () {
                                alert("名古屋の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                        });
                        }
                    } else {
                        conme1.style.display = "none";
                        conme2.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
                        conme2.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
                        conme2.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示    
                    }
                    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {//body要素をクリックしたときに非表示
                        conme1.style.display = "none";//右クリックメニューを非表示
                        conme2.style.display = "none";
                    });

                });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

最初のイベントでclass=foodのとき、追加のaddEventListenerを実行することしかやっていないですよね。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charser="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-width">
    <title>ここに記入した文字が上のタグに入る</title>

</head>
<style>
    #contextmenu1 {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 180px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #contextmenu li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #contextmenu2 {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 180px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #contextmenu2 li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<body onContextmenu="return false;">
    <div id="menu" style="width:100px; background-color:bisque; height: 300px;">
        <a class="japan" href="#">
            <p class="food">焼肉</p>
        </a>
        <a class="japan" href="#">
            <p class="food">寿司</p>
        </a>
        <a class="japan" href="#">
            <p class="food">ラーメン</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul id="contextmenu1">
        <li id="tokyo">東京</li>
        <li id="osaka">大阪</li>
        <li id="nagoya">名古屋</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="contextmenu2">
        <li>アメリカ</li>
        <li>イギリス</li>
        <li>フランス</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        let japan = document.getElementsByClassName('japan');
        let food = document.getElementsByClassName('food');
        let conme1 = document.getElementById('contextmenu1');
        let conme2 = document.getElementById('contextmenu2');

        window.onload = function () {
            for (let i = 0; i < japan.length; i++) {

                menu.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {

                    if (e.srcElement.className === "food") {//class=foodの場合

+                       conme1.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
+                       conme1.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
+                       conme1.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示
+                       conme2.style.display = "none";

                        food[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {//右クリックイベントを追加
-                           conme1.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
-                           conme1.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
-                           conme1.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示
-                           conme2.style.display = "none";

                            document.getElementById("tokyo").onclick = function () {
                                alert("東京の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                            document.getElementById("osaka").onclick = function () {
                                alert("大阪の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                            document.getElementById("nagoya").onclick = function () {
                                alert("名古屋の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }

                        });
                    } else {
                        conme1.style.display = "none";
                        conme2.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
                        conme2.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
                        conme2.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示    
                    }
                    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {//body要素をクリックしたときに非表示
                        conme1.style.display = "none";//右クリックメニューを非表示
                        conme2.style.display = "none";
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

追記

```
let japan = document.getElementsByClassName('japan');
let food = document.getElementsByClassName('food');
```

で、

```
for (let i = 0; i < japan.length; i++) {
```

でループしていて、このループの中で `food[i]` を参照しているのは、おかしいと思います。

イベントリスナーの中で別のイベントリスナーを追加していますが、これは複雑すぎます。特別な理由が無いなら、最初にすべての要素にイベントリスナーを設定すれば良いかと。

Comment: おっしゃる通りですね。ありがとうございます。しかし、上記の通りに書き換えましたが、次はcontextmenu内の関数が一度目のクリックで実行されませんでした。menuのaddEventLister内に、foodのaddEventListerがある事が原因なのでしょうか。どのようなソースコードを書けばよいかご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。

Comment: ソースコードを書き換えました。contextmenu1内にそれぞれのfood(焼肉・寿司・ラーメン)に対応した関数を持たせたいです。そうしてしまうと、どうしてもこのような形になってしまいます。これはItagakiさんのおっしゃる、特別な理由に当てはまりませんでしょうか、ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: これではまた、addEventListenerが2重になってしまい、次はcontextmenu1内の関数が1発目で発生いたしません.ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

この度は以下のように書き換えることによって、問題点は解決いたしました。

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
        let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        let japan = document.getElementsByClassName('japan');
        let food = document.getElementsByClassName('food');
        let conme1 = document.getElementById('contextmenu1');
        let conme2 = document.getElementById('contextmenu2');

        window.onload = function () {

                menu.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {

                    if (e.srcElement.className === "food") {
                        conme1.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
                        conme1.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
                        conme1.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示
                        conme2.style.display = "none";
               
                    } else {
                        conme1.style.display = "none";
                        conme2.style.left = e.pageX + "px";//メニューをマウスの位置へ移動
                        conme2.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
                        conme2.style.display = "block";//メニューを表示    
                    }
                    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {//body要素をクリックしたときにイベントを発生
                        conme1.style.display = "none";//右クリックメニューを非表示
                        conme2.style.display = "none";
                    });

                });

                for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
                        food[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {//右クリックイベントを追加

                            document.getElementById("tokyo").onclick = function () {
                                alert("東京の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                            document.getElementById("osaka").onclick = function () {
                                alert("大阪の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                            document.getElementById("nagoya").onclick = function () {
                                alert("名古屋の" + food[i].innerHTML + "です");
                            }
                        });
                    }
            }
        
    </script>
```